# Can anyone confirm in AR+ will work with iPad 4 mini (or similar iPad) running iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Can anyone confirm in AR+ will work with iPad 4 mini (or A8 and below devices) running iOS 11?

```swift
        if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {

            let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()             // 6DOF
            if #available(iOS 11.3, *) {
                configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
            sceneView.session.run(configuration)

        } else {

            let configuration = AROrientationTrackingConfiguration()       // 3DOF
            sceneView.session.run(configuration)
            print("This chipset does not meet the minimum requirements.")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to search a little bit before asking.

[Support ARKit in lower end devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014284/support-arkit-in-lower-end-devices)

It will work only on devices with A9 processor and higher, so no iPad 4 mini.